# How can I do unit testing for retrofit callbacks?

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to create unitest case for  retrofit 2 callbacks  in android. I use for test mockito, MockWebServer  and  MockResponse.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
/**
     * Actualiza el numero telefonico para el usuario
     *
     * @param phoneNumber
     */
    public  void phoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        HttpService service = Service.createService(HttpService.class, TOKEN);
        Call<Void> call = service.phonumber(phoneNumber, new User("", ""));
        call.enqueue(callback());
    }

    /**
     * @return Callback<Void>
     */
    public Callback<Void> callback() {
        return new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    dummy();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "problema");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, " " + t);
            }
        };
    }

    public void dummy(){
        System.out.println(" called");
    }
}
```

My unitest class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestLoginFragment {
   MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        spyLoginFragment = mock(LoginFragment.class);
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
    }


    @Test
    public void testDummyIsCalled() {
        spyLoginFragment.phoneNumber("3333335");
        mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(201));
        verify(spyLoginFragment, times(1)).dummy();
    }
}
```

But when you run the test I get:

```
TestLoginFragment > testDummyIsCalled FAILED
    Wanted but not invoked:
    loginFragment.dummy();
```

I'm new making callback test, how can I verify that `dummy()` was called?

Comment: It will be much simpler if you just call execute(), which will perform the request synchronously. What are you planning on testing? That the rest client works, or the response of your app to its success/failure?

Comment: hi @fractalwrench,  I 'm trying testing of response (success/failure) checking that functon dummy() was called. how I can call execute() ?

Comment: Just do call.execute(), it'd be worth checking the retrofit docs if you're unsure on the difference between execute() and enqueue()

Comment: I 'm the difference between execute() and enqueue()  on my fragment,  and need asynchronous call, but How can I do unit testing for retrofit callbacks in my fragment Login?. checking in onResponse and onFailure for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, unit test only tests the functionality of the units themselves. Therefore, it may not catch integration errors.

You shouldn´t test the retrofit framework or its callbacks, you must be presumed that retrofit always works. Only Test your code, so create a test for phoneNumber(String phoneNumber) that checks if the service was configured correctly (not need to launch retrofit service), and create others test to check the posible responses from the server in OnSuccess or OnFailure cases.

PD: If you want to test the coupling between the Retrofit call and the callback's methods, then you're talking about "integration test".